# react native run ios build succeeded but it's doesn't show

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm using react-native. I want to run my project on iOS simulator.
at the first time when I run below code everything work fine.

```
sudo react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone XR"
```

after I uninstalled my project on simulator, above code doesn't work and my project doesn't show(icon of my project doesn't appear on simulator.).

my solutions:

```
> I restarted the simulator. 
> turn off and turn on simulator.
> sudo rm -rf ios/build;
> sudo react-native run-ios
> react-native run-ios
```

but above solutions does't works.

Comment: Have you tried building from Xcode?

Comment: now it worked. tnx

Comment: 99 times out of 100 if it doesn't work with `react-native run-ios` running it from Xcode will make it work, or it will at least give you a better error message. One thing I am not sure about is why you are running the code with `sudo`. It shouldn't need that.

Answer (score 0):

try run with xcode 
open **dir** your **project** and in terminal and run **open ios**, open **projectname.xcodeproj** but if you use cocopods run open **projectname.xcworkspace**

Answer (score 0):

The simulator was renamed to `iPhone Xʀ`.
Notice: the R is styled!